# Sql login exception in Java

Tags: java, eclipse

I am getting an exception in Java while connecting to SQL. The error says

```
"Login failed for user abc    "
```

But never in my code have I user

"abc    " (with whitespaces at end)

Username is "abc" only.
What is the reason behind the exception?

Thanks.

Comment: the username who tried to login is abc ? or not?

Comment: The username is abc. And the exception says username as abc(with whitespaces at end).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you hard-code it in your source or you get the string from somewhere? I have a feeling that this is a simple typo, otherwise, check for any method that may have appended a space character to the end of a string. You might have this string stored in a database/file that has this extra space.

For a quick and dirty solution, trim the String before you pass it for login.

Answer (score 2):

My guess:

- You get the username from SQL.
- The Schema use `CHAR(N)` type.

In SQL, `CHAR(N)` type is always padded with space to the length. If you don't want this, use `VARCHAR(N)`