# Throwing SQLException when creating a connection.

Tags: java, sql, jdbc, exception

Why do we have to throw the SQLException whilst creating a jdbc connection, what is the purpose of it? And what type of exception is it? checked, runtime, unchecked?

Comment: Did you check the javadoc?

Comment: I think this is a duplicate.Did you check: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18512600/java-sql-exception http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7074754/sql-login-exception-in-java http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13748811/java-jdbc-sql-exception

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQLException derives from Exception but *not* RuntimeException, so it is **checked**.

SQLException exception is one weak point of JDBC in my opinion. It basically means 'something's gone wrong somewhere' - it's just one exception class for any number of possible causes, and you'll have to read the cause + stack trace to determine what.

Just some possible causes of SQLException:

- Failed to connect to database because URL is wrong
- Failed to connect to database because database not listening on that port
- Failed to connect to database because database server not running
- Failed to connect to database because username/password not valid
- Syntax error in SQL statement
- Row/table in SQL statement does not exist
- You've forgotten to fill in all parameters in Prepared Statement
- Column index out of bounds in ResultSet
- The moon is in the wrong phase

In other words, one exception for so many different causes. Although SQL exception is a checked exception (meaning it must eventually be caught, you can't ignore it), some of the possible causes would be better served by an unchecked exception because they cannot arise as a result of user action or mis-configuration, only as programmer error. (e.g. forgetting to give values for all parameters, or out of range column index in ResultSet).

Your question is specifically about opening connections, so the first reasons in my (incomplete) list are most relevant here. SQLException is checked, which is appropriate when opening connections because the availability of a database connection is ultimately outside the control of the Java program, so the program must handle the cases where the connection cannot be opened. The purpose of the exception in this case is to allow you to write code which will handle those situations.

Answer (score 0):

From OracleDocs:

> Each SQLException provides several kinds of information:
>
> - a string describing the error. This is used as the Java Exception    message, available via the method getMesasge.
> - a "SQLstate" string, which follows either the XOPEN SQLstate    conventions or the SQL:2003 conventions. The values of the SQLState
>     string are described in the appropriate spec. The DatabaseMetaData
>     method getSQLStateType can be used to discover whether the driver
>     returns the XOPEN type or the SQL:2003 type.
> - an integer error code that is specific to each vendor. Normally this    will be the actual error code returned by the underlying
>     database.
> - a chain to a next Exception. This can be used to provide additional    error information.
> - the causal relationship, if any for this SQLException.

More info can be found in here http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/SQLException.html
and here : http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/sqlexception.html

Also please next time do a research before you post such question, it does not take a lot of effort to type what you want in "GoogLe"

Comment: Whilst I acknowledge you have answered the question, I do not agree with the 'google it' advice sometimes given. Google will crawl this question and answer, and this page will show up in Google search results. I have, on many occasions, googled something and found countless hits of questions similar to mine, and answers saying nothing but 'google it'. Not useful.

Comment: @NickJ well it all depends on person really, i prefer to do my research before i ask a question,. But its always worth looking on net before asking as it creates less junk and it gives better understanding of the problem and possible solutions to it

Comment: Asking online does not create more junk. Lazy answers such as 'Google it' pollute search results and make research harder. Proper answers will add to useful search results thus enabling easier searches for the future. It's understandable to be annoyed by those who don't make the effort (or those who simply have not found the exact search terms they need) but if people don't want to provide a proper answer, they should say nothing at all. No criticism of you - you did answer properly.